# createBottomTabNavigator does not renders createStackNavigator when clicked

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I am following the react-navigation tutorial and everything was working fine until I tried using `createBottomTabNavigator` , I am passing two `createStackNavigator` to `createBottomTabNavigator`, the first screen showing meals categories is rendered without any issue but when I press Favorite Tab(the one with star icon) then I am greeted with the blank screen, `FavNavigator` is not getting rendered at all.
I tried replacing `FavNavigator` with `FavoritesScreen` component and it's being shown but the header bar is missing.

Here is app:

[image]

Here is the navigator configuration code:

```
import React from "react";
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "react-navigation-tabs";
import { createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import { Ionicons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from "react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs";

import CategoriesScreen from "../screens/CategoriesScreen";
import CategoryMealsScreen from "../screens/CategoryMealsScreen";
import MealsDetailScreen from "../screens/MealsDetailScreen";
import FavoritesScreen from "../screens/FavoritesScreen";
import Colors from "../constans/Colors";
import { Platform } from "react-native";

const defaultStackNavOptions = {
  headerStyle: {
    backgroundColor: Platform.OS === "android" ? Colors.primaryColor : ""
  },
  headerTintColor: Platform.OS === "android" ? "white" : Colors.primaryColor,
  headerTitle: "A Screen"
};

const MealsNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Categories: {
      screen: CategoriesScreen
    },
    CategoryMeals: {
      screen: CategoryMealsScreen
    },
    MealDetail: MealsDetailScreen
  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: defaultStackNavOptions
  }
);

const FavNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Favorites: FavoritesScreen,
    MealDetail: MealsDetailScreen
  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: defaultStackNavOptions
  }
);

const tabScreenConfig = {
  Meals: {
    screen: MealsNavigator,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarIcon: tabInfo => {
        return (
          <Ionicons name="ios-restaurant" size={25} color={tabInfo.tintColor} />
        );
      },
      tabBarColor: Colors.primaryColor
    }
  },
  Favorites: {
    screen: FavNavigator,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarIcon: tabInfo => {
        return <Ionicons name="ios-star" size={25} color={tabInfo.tintColor} />;
      },
      tabBarColor: Colors.accentColor
    }
  }
};

const MealsFavTabNavigator =
  Platform.OS === "android"
    ? createMaterialBottomTabNavigator(tabScreenConfig, {
        activeTintColor: "white",
        shifting: true,
        barStyle: {
          backgroundColor: Colors.primaryColor
        }
      })
    : createBottomTabNavigator(tabScreenConfig, {
        tabBarOptions: {
          activeTintColor: Colors.accentColor
        }
      });

export default createAppContainer(MealsFavTabNavigator);
```

Thanks in advance.

Full code: 
[GitHub](https://github.com/TheKetan2/ReactNative_Maximillian_Udemy/tree/master/meals_app)

Comment: Of what i saw, it looks like your `MealsList` component is a function, so that's surely a problem if you are just returning it as a react component

Comment: converted ```MealsList``` to the class-based component but it's still not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar issue today. I salved it by downgrading/upgrading react-native-screens to version: "react-native-screens": "2.1.0". Before was 2.4